# django.db.utils.IntegrityError:

Tags: python, django

> django.db.utils.IntegrityError: The row in table 'main_tutorial' with primary key '1' has an invalid foreign key: main_tutorial.tutorial_series_id contains a value 'tutorial_series_id' that does not have a corresponding value in main_tutorialseries.id.

The above error shows up and cant migrate

These are my models:

```
    from django.db import models
    from datetime import datetime
    #Create your models here.

    class TutorialCategory(models.Model):
        tutorial_category = models.CharField(max_length=200)
        category_summary = models.CharField(max_length=200)
        category_slug = models.CharField(max_length=200, default=1)

        class Meta:
            #Gives the proper plural name for admin
            verbose_name_plural = "Categories"

        def __str__(self):
            return self.tutorial_category

    class TutorialSeries(models.Model):
        tutorial_series = models.CharField(max_length=200)
        tutorial_category = models.ForeignKey(TutorialCategory, default=1,verbose_name="Category", on_delete=models.SET_DEFAULT)
        series_summary = models.CharField(max_length=200)

        class Meta:
            #Otherwise we get "Tutorial Serie*ss* in admin"
            verbose_name_plural = "Series"

        def __str__(self):
            return self.tutorial_series

    class Tutorial(models.Model):
        tutorial_title = models.CharField(max_length=200)
        tutorial_content = models.TextField()
        tutorial_published = models.DateTimeField("date published", default = datetime.now())
        tutorial_series = models.ForeignKey(TutorialSeries, default=1, verbose_name="Series", on_delete=models.SET_DEFAULT)
        tutorial_slug = models.CharField(max_length=200,default=1)

        def __str__(self):
            return self.tutorial_title
```

Comment: as you have used `default=1` in **tutorial_published =models.DateTimeField("datepublished",  default=datetime.now())**, are you sure you have a `TutorialSeries` data with id 1? Can you check it in the shell whether **TutorialSeries.objects.get(id=1)** exists?

Comment: Am new to django...what code do I run in my shell?

Comment: In your terminal(where you do `python manage.py runserver`), open the shell by typing **python manage.py shell**, then you are prompted to the django shell. Then import your models there as ** from your_path.models import TutorialSeries **. Then check if the data exists as: ** TutorialSeries.objects.get(id=1) **

Comment: On importing it just stays there... nothing further is displayed

Comment: That is what happens. It just stays there and you need to enter the next command I said. To solve your problem, Try the answer below.

Answer (score 16):

I faced the same problem just I am also working with the same. All you got to do is to

> just delete "migrations" folder from the "main()" and also the db.sqlite file too.
>
> The error is probably occurring because we have Tutorial already in db
> which is not linked to TutorialSeries so.., to make it linked to the
> db, make the changes above and then again perform commands.

What I got was:

```
python manage.py makemigrations
```

Output:

```
No changes detected
```

Next one

```
python manage.py migrate
```

Output:

```
Operations to perform:
  Apply all migrations: admin, auth, contenttypes, sessions
Running migrations:
  Applying contenttypes.0001_initial... OK
  Applying auth.0001_initial... OK
  Applying admin.0001_initial... OK
  Applying admin.0002_logentry_remove_auto_add... OK
  Applying admin.0003_logentry_add_action_flag_choices... OK
  Applying contenttypes.0002_remove_content_type_name... OK
  Applying auth.0002_alter_permission_name_max_length... OK
  Applying auth.0003_alter_user_email_max_length... OK
  Applying auth.0004_alter_user_username_opts... OK
  Applying auth.0005_alter_user_last_login_null... OK
  Applying auth.0006_require_contenttypes_0002... OK
  Applying auth.0007_alter_validators_add_error_messages... OK
  Applying auth.0008_alter_user_username_max_length... OK
  Applying auth.0009_alter_user_last_name_max_length... OK
  Applying auth.0010_alter_group_name_max_length... OK
  Applying auth.0011_update_proxy_permissions... OK
  Applying sessions.0001_initial... OK
```

> Make sure while performing these commands you have linked Tutorial
> with TutorialSeries. And guys making things done this way makes you earlier data lost from the database. Be careful about that.

Have a Nice day & happy coding.

Comment: Have a nice day!  Thanks 10k.

Comment: how about if we don't want to delete database.

Comment: deleting migrations folder is not advised, delete migrations instead

Comment: lol this way just for fun :D u will lost client data if u do like this on production env

Answer (score 8):

You can simply delete all the objects in the main_tutorial table from django shell:

1. goto command prompt
2. `python manage.py shell`
3. `from main.models import Tutorial`
4. `Tutorial.objects.all().delete()`

(main being the app name here)

This will delete all the objects in the Tutorial table and then makemigrations and migrate and it should work just fine.

Comment: Isn't the whole point of migrations that django should be able to gracefully migrate data from one version of the database to another? Doesn't deleting everything defeat that?

Answer (score 3):

In your **Tutorial** model, you are using a default value for the foreign key field ** tutorial_series **. This causes the migration to check if a record in `TutorialSeries` exists with `id=1` but there is no such data present, so the error is occuring.

To avoid the error while migrating, remove the `on_delete=models.SET_DEFAULT` and `default=1` from our fields to make your models as:

```
class TutorialSeries(models.Model):
    tutorial_series = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    tutorial_category = models.ForeignKey(TutorialCategory,verbose_name="Category")
    series_summary = models.CharField(max_length=200)

    class Meta:
        #Otherwise we get "Tutorial Serie*ss* in admin"
        verbose_name_plural = "Series"

    def __str__(self):
        return self.tutorial_series

class Tutorial(models.Model):
        tutorial_title = models.CharField(max_length=200)
        tutorial_content = models.TextField()
        tutorial_published = models.DateTimeField("date published", default = datetime.now())
        tutorial_series = models.ForeignKey(TutorialSeries, verbose_name="Series", blank=True, null=True) #<--changes
        tutorial_slug = models.CharField(max_length=200,default=1)

        def __str__(self):
            return self.tutorial_title
```

After this, migrate your models. Then add data to **TutorialCategory** and **TutorialSeries** with `id=1`.

Then revert your models to your initial setup **(keeping default=1 and on_delete=models.SET_DEFAULT)**. Then again run makemigrations and migrate your models. After this, your problem might be solved.

Comment: Is your database fresh or have you inserted any data in the tables?

Comment: Also, you need to remove the `default=1` for field **tutorial_category** in **TutorialSeries** model.

Comment: ERRORS:
main.TutorialSeries.tutorial_category: (fields.E321) Field specifies on_delete=SET_DEFAULT, but has no default value.
        HINT: Set a default value, or change the on_delete rule.

Comment: SET_DEFAULT is to be used if you know default tutorial_category won't be deleted. So, a solution is that you can comment the models that are inheriting other models as foreign key, perform a migration, add a data to that model, then uncomment the model that referred the previously migrated model and so on.

Comment: You can then use default=1. But make sure that the model being referenced contains a data with the id specified in `default`.

Comment: Check my updated answer. So, what you need to do is define your models without `default=1` and `on_delete=models.SET_DEFAULT` in your foreign key fields. Then run the migrations, add data to the models(TutorialCategory and TutorialSeries), change the models as you have defined in the question, and migrate.

Answer (score 2):

Try to delete all the migration files exept `__init__.py` and also delete db.sqlite3. After that run makemigrations and migrate again

Answer (score 0):

Try using `on_delete = models.CASCADE` without a default parameter.

Answer (score 0):

I was dealing with the same issue. I deleted everything inside migrations except _init__.py and also the sqlite database. Then ran- py -3.7 manage.py makemigrations, then after that, py -3.7 manage.py migrate. Then it worked!

Answer (score 0):

I had this issue a while ago. 
The above answer maybe correct but it didnt work for me because 
-im using postgres, i cant just delete the database
-migration files were commited in git.

My situation was, I have 004 migration file but i cant run it because of IntegrityError.

I checked the file, and i saw it was in `operation` list.

The first item of list is `migrations.CreateModel` and the second was `migrations.AddField`

here are my steps:

1. I **commented** the second item in list, only the `CreateModel` is remaining.
2. then run the `migrate`
3. open the django admin page and add it manually the missing id
   you can add it also in database editor or `update` statement.
4. uncomment the `AddField` section and rerun the `migrate`.

Answer (score 0):

```
from django.db import models
from datetime import datetime


class TutorialCategory(models.Model):
    tutorial_category = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    category_summary = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    category_slug = models.CharField(max_length=200)

    class Meta:
        verbose_name_plural = "Categories"

    def __str__(self):
        return self.tutorial_category

class TutorialSeries(models.Model):
    tutorial_series = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    tutorial_category = models.ForeignKey(TutorialCategory, verbose_name="Category", on_delete=models.CASCADE, blank=True, null=True)
    series_summary = models.CharField(max_length=200)

    class Meta:
        verbose_name_plural = "Series"

    def __str__(self):
        return self.tutorial_series

class Tutorial(models.Model):
    tutorial_title = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    tutorial_content = models.TextField()
    tutorial_published = models.DateTimeField('date published', default=datetime.now)

    tutorial_series = models.ForeignKey(TutorialSeries, verbose_name="Series", on_delete=models.CASCADE, blank=True, null=True)
    tutorial_slug = models.CharField(max_length=200, default=1)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.tutorial_title
```

Try this, it's work for me.

But remember, you will need to type this code before you have done "python3 manage.py makemigrations" and "python3 manage.py migrate"

Answer (score -1):

The following answer was been posted on the Django tutorial comments of sentdex by nice folks namely: "Kevin di" and "JOSEPH Blessingh". The recommendation helped me and worked like charm:

There is a file  " db.sqlite3 " in your working directory, you can open it with any database management tools that supports SQLite type.
following the steps:

1. For example, " DB Browser for SQLite ", you can Google and download it.
2. Opening the " db.sqlite3 " file, navigate to the  Tables.
3. Find the main_tutorial table. (Maybe you used another table name in the previous lessons, use your table name.)
4. Delete record from the table: main_tutorial.
5. Try python manage.py migrate again.

The meaning of Delete Record from the table can be explained as:
- Click main_tutorial
- Then you might see a tab with the name Browse Data
- Click it and you will see your records
-  Press Ctrl + Left Mouse button on the number on the left hand side column to select all the rows
- Delete them using right click