# IntegrityError Primary Key Invalid (python-django)

Tags: python, django, python-3.x, django-models

I'm looking at a sentdex lesson and I have this error and why ?

I saw a similar question here but couldn't get the answer

```
from django.db import models
from datetime import datetime
# Create your models here.

class tutorialcategory(models.Model):
    tutorial_category=models.CharField(max_length=200)
    category_summary=models.CharField(max_length=200)
    category_slug=models.CharField(max_length=200, default=1)

    class Meta:
        verbose_name_plural="Categories"

    def __str__(self):
        return self.tutorial_category

class tutorialseries(models.Model):
    tutorial_series=models.CharField(max_length=200)
    tutorial_category=models.ForeignKey(tutorialcategory,  verbose_name="Category",  on_delete=models.SET_DEFAULT)
    series_summary=models.CharField(max_length=200)

    class Meta:
        verbose_name_plural="series"

    def __str__(self):
        return self.tutorial_series


class tutorial(models.Model):
    tutorial_title=models.CharField(max_length=200)
    tutorial_content=models.TextField()
    tutorial_published=models.DateTimeField("date published", default=datetime.now())

    tutorial_series=models.ForeignKey(tutorialseries, default=1, verbose_name="series", on_delete=models.SET_DEFAULT)
    tutorial_slug=models.CharField(max_length=200, default=1)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.tutorial_title
```

Below is how the error looks like:

> django.db.utils.IntegrityError: The row in table 'main_tutorial' with
>   primary key '1' has an invalid foreign key:
>   main_tutorial.tutorial_series_id contains a value '1' that does not
>   have a corresponding value in main_tutorialseries.id.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [django.db.utils.IntegrityError:](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56374172/django-db-utils-integrityerror)

Answer (score 1):

#### Answer:

On `tutorial` model do you have a foreign key `tutorial_series` defined as:

```
tutorial_series=models.ForeignKey(tutorialseries, default=1, ...
```

This FK (Foreign Key) has as default value **1**, but, when you execute your code, you are trying to save a `tutorial` but **they are not any `tutorial_series` with `Id = 1`**.

Try to create a `tutorialseries` (with Id=1) or just change the default value to None. Like this:

```
tutorial_series=models.ForeignKey(tutorialseries, null=True, blank=True, ...
```

#### About your question:

You set a title of this post:

> IntegrityError Primary Key Invalid (python-django)

But, what is invalid, is not the Primary Key. **What is invalid is the foreign key.**

Comment: tutorial_series=models.CharField(max_length=200). this change?

Comment: @koki, read my answer for twice. `CharField` is not a `ForeignKey`. This will remove the error but the sense of the code is not the same.