# django.db.utils.IntegrityError: - error persists

Tags: django, django-models, generic-foreign-key

this question has been discussed and answered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56374172/django-db-utils-integrityerror/56375323#56375323?newreg=73022ae9a9aa4980baef2558c5c47fd3), however the error is persisting for me.  As I don't have enough reputation I cant comment in that discussion yet.

I have followed the responses to remove `on_delete=models.SET_DEFAULT` and `default=1` to run the initial migrate, however I receive the following error:

```
*tutorial_category = models.ForeignKey(TutorialCategory,verbose_name="Category", null=True)
TypeError: __init__() missing 1 required positional argument: 'on_delete'*
```

I'm assuming it needs the 'on_delete' field, and have tried `on_delete.PROTECT and CASCADE`, however this brings the original error:

```
*"django.db.utils.IntegrityError: The row in table 'main_tutorial' with primary key '1' has an invalid foreign key: main_tutorial.tutorial_series_id contains a value 'tutorial_series_id' that does not have a corresponding value in main_tutorialseries.id."*
```

I am using Django 2.2.9, any help on how to set up Foreignkeys would be appreciated.

thanks!

Comment: Are you getting the error on your very first migration? Or have you run migrations in that app before?

Comment: had multiple failed migrations, deleted all of those out of the migrations folder (leaving __init__.py) before trying different values for on_delete.  none have been successful

Comment: I tested the code in the post you quoted and it worked as is. No migration error - nothing. So that is probably not the issue. I experienced similar issues in the past when incorrrect migrations had already been put into the database. Would it be possible to give the whole project a fresh start, that is create a new django project, copy in all your code and migrate from there?

Comment: I had a feeling previous migrations will cause issues.  Can start again as I'm just doing a learning tutorial anyway  
Going forward when I move to an actual project, is it best to just backup before attempting any migrations? I'm guessing there's no debugging abilities if you wreck it

Comment: A backup is always a good idea. In fact it is possible to revert migrations that failed half way. If the the migrations failed before touching the db it is just a matter of deleting the migration files as you did. If the db has been touched you need to open the db and delete the rows with the failed migrations form the table django_migrations in addition to deleting the files. But be careful: Always start with the last migration

Answer (score 0):

**Try anyone of these:**

```
tutorial_category = models.ForeignKey(on_delete=django.db.models.deletion.DO_NOTHING,TutorialCategory,verbose_name="Category", null=True)

tutorial_category = models.ForeignKey(on_delete=models.CASCADE,TutorialCategory,verbose_name="Category", null=True)
```

Comment: both didn't work.

for django.db.models.deletion.DO_NOTHING it errored as the name Django was not defined

Comment: Anyone solved the issue? Have this problem myself after I tried to redefine one field as FK to another table I got an error about invalid values not present in FK table. However after I removed the FK link the error persisted and nothing was working. It is like the migrations mechanism got corrupted.